# Upper case author names for BST file (based on APA)

Tags: bibtex, natbib, small-caps, custom-bib

I have created a .bst file using makebst. It is based on the APA style.
I have compared the .bst file to other bst files, and trying unsuccessfully to put the authors in the bibliography in capitals.

I have uploaded the files, .bst and .dbj (17KB) to:
[BST and DBJ](http://www.mediafire.com/?j6145dtgn56t2bt)

Answer (score 6):

### Fancy hacking

I think the simpler solution is just to hack you `bst` file. So, for example look in the `apalike2.bst` file for

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names }
  if$
}
```

and add `smallcaps` before `format.names` so that it looks like

```
{ author smallcaps format.names }
```

Here I added the `smallcaps` function near `FUNCTION {emphasize}`, and it is defined as

```
FUNCTION {smallcaps}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "{\sc " swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

The result is shown below:

[image]

It works with `apa.bst` too, as shown below:

[image]

### Using makebst

Otherwise, you can use [makebst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/), and generate your own format, e.g.

```
$ latex makebst
```

will ask you a series of questions about the format of your bibliography, including typeface about authors:

```
TYPEFACE FOR AUTHORS IN LIST OF REFERENCES:
(*) Normal font for author names 
(s) Small caps authors (\sc)
(i) Italic authors (\it or \em)
(b) Bold authors (\bf)
(u) User defined author font (\bibnamefont)
  Select:

\ans=s
  You have selected: Small caps authors
```

When the above steps are completed, you can just run `latex` on the filename you gave, and you'll have your `bst` file. Below is the result. (I accepted all default choices, so you may have to tweak it to fit the APA style.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, the coding instructions didn't work, so I had to run the makebst again. Makebst worked when I selected smallcaps. I also followed the log file (dbj) of cds.bst which is almost similar to what I need. ([LINK](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~wgm/custombib/problem/all_authors_test/makebst_cds.log "cds.bst log")

Comment: @F Mitchell Good to hear you finally solved your problem.