# Unwanted uppercases in bibliography names and in captions

Tags: bibliographies, floats, apa-style, small-caps, french

when I use the apa6 or article document class in english, there is no problem. But when I put it in french the names of authors in apa style (with apalike) are with uppercases and it's the same about the captions ("FIGURE 1 : caption of the..." and I'd like "Figure 1 : ...")

I did't found something that works on internet (or maybe I didn't made it well).
About the bibliography tried that : [Upper case author names for BST file (based on APA)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16705/upper-case-author-names-for-bst-file-based-on-apa).
Other stuff proposing to put commands in the preamble and it didn't worked also.

Thank you !

====

Edit :

Thank you Ralf Stubner, that works great ! And the keywords texdoc frenchb permitted me to find that, that will help me a lot in the future : http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel-french/frenchb.pdf

(Yes, the first account was a guest one (was a stupid idea), I go to ask to merge them, thank you. Thank you also for explaining to me how works this forum.)

So, with the Ralf Stubner patch and using apacite as you advised Alan Munn, everything works, thanks !

```
\documentclass[french]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\frenchsetup{SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

Some stuff with the reference \cite{ref}.

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{The letter A}
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{fig.png}
\end{figure}


\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bib}


\end{document}
```

Result :

[image: result]

Instead of that before your help :

[image: bad result]

So I guess that's good for me (hope it will works on my computer as on overleaf), thank you again !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. It's hard to know exactly what you're doing from your question. Can you construct a small, compilable document that shows the problem, and edit your question to include that code. Most of the formatting changes you see are being done by the `french` option of `babel`. Some may be able to be turned off. See the `babel` documentation for how to do that. The `apalike` style is quite old, and doesn't really implement true APA style. I would use either the `apacite` package along with the `apacite` bibliography style or `biblatex` with the `style=apa` option.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify how you "put [the document] in french". E.g., do you load the `babel` package with the option `french`?

Comment: In french, the authors names is not exactly in uppercase– it is (or should be)in small caps. Maybe you should use `biblatex-apa` to easily customise if necessary.

Comment: @Mico: a typo, due to my computer behaviour. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer about small cap "Figure": From the documentation of the `french` language in `babel`, which on my system I can read with `texdoc frenchb`, one learns that the command `\frenchsetup` takes the argument `SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false` to turn off using small caps for figure and table name.

Minimal Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchsetup{SmallCapsFigTabCaptions=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{The letter A}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]