# Bibtex: \Makeuppercase Authors har2nat Bibtex

Tags: miktex, bibliographystyle, uppercase

TeXdistribution: MiKTeX 21.2

I am using `bibtex` & for my bibliography `\usepackage{har2nat}`. Changed the `agsm`-style  (renamed it to `agsm-my` & changed `\bibliographystyle{agsm-my}`).

The 2 changes I did in `agsm-my` are

1. Get rid of the quote in the titles, as done here [Fine tuning the agsm bibliography style, and adding links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65942/fine-tuning-the-agsm-bibliography-style-and-adding-links) . Which gave me the expected outcome

[image: unquoted titels]

2. I want to have all authors in uppercase. For this I inserted in `agsm-my` (according to [Upper case author names for BST file (based on APA)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16705/upper-case-author-names-for-bst-file-based-on-apa))

s

```
FUNCTION {makeuppercase}     
{duplicate$ empty$
{pop$ "" }
{ "{\MakeUppercase{" swap$ * "}" * }
if$
}


FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" author makeuppercase format.names }
  if$
}
```

(`FUNCTION {makeuppercase}` is located after `FUNCTION {emphasize}{ [...]}`)
but I am getting additional **ands** as a results between the names (see Ojovan, M. I.) & I do not want them:

[image: issue]

What causes the **and** to occur & how can I solve it? Or is there another possibility to change the author names all in uppercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe not exactly the answer you want, but here's an MWE that gets you uppercase last names only using BibLaTeX:

```
%dummy bib - just use your own external file for the real thing
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{abib.bib}
@Article{Fuller.2018.A,
  author  = {Mark E. Fuller and Richard H. West and C. Franklin Goldsmith},
  title   = {A Computational Investigation into the Combustion Byproducts of a Liquid Monopropellant},
  journal = {Proceedings of the Combustion Institute},
  year    = {2019},
  volume  = {37},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {5671--5677},
  doi     = {10.1016/j.proci.2018.05.175},
}
\end{filecontents*}
% dummy bib ends here

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    %backend=biber,  % optional, but I think biber is the future
    style=apa,  % this style seems to be mostly what you want
    %doi=true, % set true/false to show/hide doi (options also for ISBN, etc.)
]{biblatex}

%here's how you could put that annoying "AND" in or change it to somethign else
%\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{AND}\space} 

%new author name convention
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}} %makes names uppercase
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{} %blank field wipes out given name
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{} %prefix name field
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{} %suffix name field

\addbibresource{abib.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{Fuller.2018.A}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works.
But rather than `style=apa` the style `authoryear` is more what I am looking for. Also,  `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}` has the disadvantage to make the citation also in upper case which I do not want.

Comment: To just have the author in the bibliography in upper case it is better to use `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}`